# Pull-Push are not working on IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to use `IntelliJ 14.1.4` git integration but so far I am unsuccessful. I remember it was working on version 13 and early versions of 14. I have git on my Windows 10. Here is the list of what I'd tried:

- Git works as expected using command line (pull-push and ...)
- Git on IntelliJ works jus for local commands( commit and ...)
- I have setup all my Github stuff in IntelliJ and when I press `test` button it says `successful`
- I can even see my repositories on Github using the Git plugin
- I re-installed everything (Git, IntelliJ)

but when I try to `push`  or `pull` from Github it starts the process but it never get finished or even it doesn't throw any exception and I have to kill the Git process using Task Manager. What could be wrong?

Comment: What url are you using? https or ssh?

Comment: by default https but I also changed the config file in .git to ssh adn it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where git on IntelliJ only worked for local commands. Here's how I solved it:

1. Update Git to the latest version (at the time of writing this answer: `2.42.1`)
2. Restart IntelliJ and then perform git push.
3. A message box will appear on the screen, like this:
   [image: Git asking for credentials before pushing]
4. Enter the credentials (for me it was my laptop's password) and git push will be successful.

Note: I'm using Mac with Sonoma 14.0, IntelliJ 2020.2, and Git 2.39.0.